# Fetch multiple emails using loop Wordpress post

Tags: php, wordpress

I fetched single email address entry using following code from post_meta:

```
global $post;
$post = $wp_query->post;
$id = $post->ID;

$custom_fields = get_post_custom($id);
$my_custom_field = $custom_fields['offer'];
    
$result = unserialize(base64_decode($my_custom_field[0]));
echo $result['email'];
```

But when I tried using foreach logo, only getting output as `SsI`:

```
custom_fields = get_post_custom($id);
    $my_custom_field = $custom_fields['offer'];
    $fetch = unserialize(base64_decode($my_custom_field[0]));
foreach($fetch as $key => $result){
    
    echo $result['email'];
}
```

Data:

```
property_status: For Sale, Property_ID: lorem ipsum, Available_From: lorem ipsum, Year_Built: lorem ipsum, Exterior_Material: lorem ipsum, Structure_Type: lorem ipsum, AC: lorem ipsum, Acres: lorem ipsum, Bedroom_Features: lorem ipsum, Cross_Streets: lorem ipsum, Dining_Area: lorem ipsum, Disability_Access: lorem ipsum, Entry_Location: lorem ipsum, Exterior_Cnstruction: lorem ipsum, Fireplace_Fuel: lorem ipsum, Fireplace_Location: lorem ipsum, Legal_Desc: lorem ipsum, Lot_Description: lorem ipsum, Lot_Size_Source: lorem ipsum, Misc_Interior: lorem ipsum, Sewer: lorem ipsum, Source_Of_Sqft: lorem ipsum, Terms: lorem ipsum, View_Desc: lorem ipsum, address: 129-133 West 22nd Street, local-area: Chelsea, latitude: 40.7427704, longitude: -73.99455039999998, city: dubai, postcode: 10011, country: USA, phone: 212245-4606, fax: 212245-4606, contact-email: test@test.com, contact_web: e-plugin.com, listing_contact_source: new_value, youtube: 0y4rXoWrJlw, facebook: test, linkedin: test, twitter: test, instagram: test, youtube_social: test, bedrooms: 4, bathrooms: 3, guest: 1, garages: 2, sale_or_rent_price: 5210641, price_postfix_text: $, area: 6000, area_postfix_text: SFT, rent_period: , _favorites: , 1, _edit_lock: 1632745077:1, offer: YTozOntzOjQ6Im5hbWUiO3M6MTA6IlNhbmFkIFFhemkiO3M6NToiZW1haWwiO3M6MTg6InNhbmFkZGZiQGdtYWlsLmNvbSI7czo3OiJtZXNzYWdlIjtzOjkxOiJJIHdvdWxkIGxpa2UgdG8gaW5xdWlyZSBhYm91dCB5b3VyIGxpc3RpbmcuIFBsZWFzZSBjb250YWN0IG1lIGF0IHlvdXIgZWFybGllc3QgY29udmVuaWVuY2UuIjt9,YTozOntzOjQ6Im5hbWUiO3M6MTA6IlNhbmFkIFFhemkiO3M6NToiZW1haWwiO3M6MTg6InNhbmFkZGZiQGdtYWlsLmNvbSI7czo3OiJtZXNzYWdlIjtzOjQ6InRlc3QiO30=, _edit_last: 1, _public_facilities: a:1:{s:4:"Shop";s:0:"";}, _plan_description_0: , state: , image_gallery_ids: , contact_name: , vimeo: , rs_page_bg_color: , site-sidebar-layout: default, site-content-layout: default, theme-transparent-header-meta: default, stick-header-meta: default
```

Can someone help to fetch all the email entries?

Comment: _"Data:"_ - what _exactly_ is that supposed to be now? What `get_post_custom($id)` returned? Or what `$result` contains?

Comment: If `$result['email']` gave you what you wanted, that means `$result` must have been an associative array. If you now `foreach` over that array, then trying to access  `$result['email']` again inside the loop, would only make sense if the top-level `email` property in your data was itself an array to begin with, and had another property with key `email` below it.